# How to use scandir() in C to list sorted subdirectories recursively

Tags: c, linux, recursion, scandir, dirent.h

I'm implementing parts of the Linux ls command in C. I want to sort the contents of directories lexicographically, which I've been doing using `scandir()`. This is easy enough for listing single directories, but I'm having trouble doing it for listing subdirectories recursively. My current code: (results in a segmentation faults once a directory type is reached)

```
void recursive(char* arg){





    int i;
    struct dirent **file_list;
    int num;
    char* next_dir;

    num = scandir(arg, &file_list, NULL, alphasort);

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) { 


        if(file_list[i]->d_type == DT_DIR) {

            if(strcmp(".", file_list[i]->d_name) != 0 && strcmp("..", file_list[i]->d_name) != 0) {


                        // Directories are printed with a colon to distinguish them from files

                        printf("%s: \n", file_list[i]->d_name);
                        strcpy(next_dir, arg);
                        strcat(next_dir, "/");
                        strcat(next_dir, file_list[i]->d_name);

                        printf("\n");

                        recursive(next_dir);
            }

        } else {

            if(strcmp(".", file_list[i]->d_name) != 0 && strcmp("..", file_list[i]->d_name) != 0) {

                printf("%s \n", file_list[i]->d_name);
            }
        }
    }



} 

int main(void) {

    recursive(".");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `next_dir` is a _pointer_ and is _not_ allocated/initialized. The cheap fix is: `char next_dir[1024 + 1];`

Comment: But, additionally, you're not freeing elements of `file_list` or `file_list` itself, which are both allocated in `scandir` with `malloc`, so you're leaking memory. Apply the "cheap" fix, but then run the program under `valgrind`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was planning on fixing the memory allocation/freeing after getting the basic mechanism working. Obviously these problems had more impact on functionality than I thought!

Comment: Have a look at `ftw` in `ftw.h` and the `fts_*` functions in `fts.h`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two recommended methods for traversing entire filesystem trees in Linux and other POSIXy systems:

- [nftw()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html): `man 3 nftw`

  Given an initial path, a callback function, the maximum number of descriptors to use, and a set of flags, `nftw()` will call the callback function once for every filesystem object in the subtree.  The order in which entries in the same directory is called is not specified, however.

  This is the POSIX.1 (IEEE 1003) function.
- [fts_open()/fts_read()/fts_children()/fts_close()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html): `man 3 fts`

  The fts interface provides a way to traverse filesystem hierarchies.  The `fts_children()` provides a linked list of filesystem entries sorted by the comparison function specified in the `fts_open()` call.  It is rather similar to how `scandir()` returns an array of filesystem entries, except that the two use very different structures to describe each filesystem entry.

  Prior to glibc 2.23 (released in 2016), the Linux (glibc) fts implementation had bugs when using 64-bit file sizes (so on x86-64, or when compiling with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`).

  These are BSD functions (FreeBSD/OpenBSD/macOS), but are available in Linux also.

Finally, there is also the atfile version of scandir(), [scandirat()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandirat.3.html), that returns the filtered and sorted filesystem entries from a specific directory, but in addition to the pathname, it takes a file descriptor to the relative root directory to be used as a parameter.  (If `AT_FDCWD` is used instead of a file descriptor, then `scandirat()` behaves like `scandir()`.)

The simplest option here is to use `nftw()`, store all walked paths, and finally sort the paths.  For example, `walk.c`:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <ftw.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct entry {
    /* Insert additional properties like 'off_t size' here. */
    char           *name;       /* Always points to name part of pathname */
    char            pathname[]; /* Full path and name */
};

struct listing {
    size_t          max;        /* Number of entries allocated for */
    size_t          num;        /* Number of entries in the array */
    struct entry  **ent;        /* Array of pointers, one per entry */
};
#define  STRUCT_LISTING_INITIALIZER  { 0, 0, NULL }

/* Locale-aware sort for arrays of struct entry pointers.
*/
static int  entrysort(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    const struct entry  *ent1 = *(const struct entry **)ptr1;
    const struct entry  *ent2 = *(const struct entry **)ptr2;
    return strcoll(ent1->pathname, ent2->pathname);
}

/* Global variable used by nftw_add() to add to the listing */
static struct listing  *nftw_listing = NULL;

static int nftw_add(const char *pathname, const struct stat *info, int typeflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf)
{
    const char *name = pathname + ftwbuf->base;

    /* These generate no code, just silences the warnings about unused parameters. */
    (void)info;
    (void)typeflag;

    /* Ignore "." and "..". */
    if (name[0] == '.' && !name[1])
        return 0;
    if (name[0] == '.' && name[1] == '.' && !name[2])
        return 0;

    /* Make sure there is room for at least one more entry in the listing. */
    if (nftw_listing->num >= nftw_listing->max) {
        const size_t   new_max = nftw_listing->num + 1000;
        struct entry **new_ent;

        new_ent = realloc(nftw_listing->ent, new_max * sizeof (struct entry *));
        if (!new_ent)
            return -ENOMEM;

        nftw_listing->max = new_max;
        nftw_listing->ent = new_ent;
    }

    const size_t  pathnamelen = strlen(pathname);
    struct entry *ent;

    /* Allocate memory for this entry.
       Remember to account for the name, and the end-of-string terminator, '\0', at end of name. */
    ent = malloc(sizeof (struct entry) + pathnamelen + 1);
    if (!ent)
        return -ENOMEM;

    /* Copy other filesystem entry properties to ent here; say 'ent->size = info->st_size;'. */

    /* Copy pathname, including the end-of-string terminator, '\0'. */
    memcpy(ent->pathname, pathname, pathnamelen + 1);

    /* The name pointer is always to within the pathname. */
    ent->name = ent->pathname + ftwbuf->base;

    /* Append. */
    nftw_listing->ent[nftw_listing->num++] = ent;

    return 0;
}

/* Scan directory tree starting at path, adding the entries to struct listing.
   Note: the listing must already have been properly initialized!
   Returns 0 if success, nonzero if error; -1 if errno is set to indicate error.
*/
int scan_tree_sorted(struct listing *list, const char *path)
{
    if (!list) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
    if (!path || !*path) {
        errno = ENOENT;
        return -1;
    }

    nftw_listing = list;

    int  result = nftw(path, nftw_add, 64, FTW_DEPTH);

    nftw_listing = NULL;

    if (result < 0) {
        errno = -result;
        return -1;
    } else
    if (result > 0) {
        errno = 0;
        return result;
    }

    if (list->num > 2)
        qsort(list->ent, list->num,  sizeof list->ent[0], entrysort);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct listing  list = STRUCT_LISTING_INITIALIZER;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        const char *arg0 = (argc > 0 && argv && argv[0] && argv[0][0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)";
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", arg0);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s .\n", arg0);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s TREE [ TREE ... ]\n", arg0);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program lists all files and directories starting at TREE,\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "in sorted order.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    for (int arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        if (scan_tree_sorted(&list, argv[arg])) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error scanning directory tree: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    printf("Found %zu entries:\n", list.num);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list.num; i++)
        printf("\t%s\t(%s)\n", list.ent[i]->pathname, list.ent[i]->name);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 walk.c -o walk`, and run using e.g. `./walk ..`.

The `scan_tree_sorted()` function calls `nftw()` for the directory specified, updating the global variable `nftw_listing` so that the `nftw_add()` callback function can add each new directory entry to it.  If the listing contains more that one entry afterwards, it is sorted using `qsort()` and a locale-aware comparison function (based on `strcoll()`).

`nftw_add()` skips `.` and `..`, and adds every other pathname to the listing structure `nftw_listing`.  It automatically grows the array as needed in linear fashion; the `new_max = nftw_listing->num + 1000;` means we allocate in units of a thousand (pointers).

The `scan_tree_sorted()` can be called multiple times with the same listing as the target, if one wants to list disjoint subtrees in one listing.  Note, however, that it does not check for duplicates, although those could easily be filtered out after the qsort.